# Custom datamodel setter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, enums, entity-framework-6

I'm using EF6 Code First and I got a Job with the following properties:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }
public DateTime? EndTime { get; set; }
public JobResult Result { get; set; }
public JobStatus Status { get; set; }
```

The Status property should be set depending on the other properties of the job (as shown in SetStatus() below).

Right now I'm manually calling an update method of Job whenever I update the properties.

```
public void SetStatus()
{
    if (Result == null && StartTime == null)
        status = JobStatus.Pending;
    else if (Result == null)
        status = JobStatus.Running;
    else if (Result.Error == null)
        status = JobStatus.Finished;
    else
        status = JobStatus.Error;
}
```

I'd like to have this done automatically every time I set any of the properties of the job. However that would require me to customize the setters and getters and have private variables which in EF is not supported.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add an additional property with the attribute

```
[NotMapped]
```

The properties will be ignored.